# How to define a addition and multiplication operators over a set R U {infinity} U {-infinity}?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

[image]

And, are the sets {infinity} and {-infinity} actually infinite sequences in their respective directions, such that I could define the operators as such? :

- = a(x1, ...) = (ax1, ax2, ...)
- = (x1, ...) + (y2, ...) = (x1+y1, x2+y2, ...)

Comment: You are overthinking this. There are no sequences here. The set you are to decide about is just the real numbers with two extra symbols. Call them $A$ and $B$ and forget about infinity. Then check the vector space axioms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addition is not associative:

$$(-\infty+\infty)+\infty = (0)+\infty = \infty$$

$$-\infty+(\infty+\infty) = -\infty+(\infty) = 0$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: combine the first and third assumptions on the bottom line about addition and subtraction with infinities to derive a contradiction.